# Facebook Open Graph dosent work (share, comment, like...)

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-opengraph

When i debug a page from my website it gives me this error:

> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Object Missing a Required Value
>
> Object at URL 'http://dimityr_qlamov.example.com/bg/book/Balada+na+syrceto/1276' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

but i dont see any mistake inside the code:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://dimityr_qlamov.example.com/bg/book/Balada+na+syrceto/1276" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Балада на сърцето Димитър Яламов izdavam.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://izdavam.com/publics/img/book/cover/thumb/cover-1276_140_200.jpg" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="18292642177****"/> 
<meta property="fb:admins" content="505465***"/>
```

Can you please give me some advice what is wrong, because i google and i also read all the questions in stackoverflow, but i couldn't find an answer for my problem. thank you!

Comment: What is the url to your page?

Comment: it is http://dimityr_qlamov.izdavam.com/bg/book/Balada+na+syrceto/1276

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdimityr_qlamov.izdavam.com%2Fbg%2Fbook%2FBalada%2Bna%2Bsyrceto%2F1276 works for me

Comment: yes, but still it gives an error. "Object Missing a Required Value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange, but this have fixed without me doing anything to the code. So, at the end of the day i dont know how this thing got fixed, but now i dont get the error anymore.